# "Advanced network settings > Data usage" statistics using PowerShell

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, nic, statistics

How can one get the `Advanced network settings > Data usage` statistics in Windows 11 using PowerShell?

[image]

I couldn't figure out how to get the total data consumption per process using [`Get-NetAdapterStatistics`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterstatistics?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-1-display-statistics-for-the-specified-network-adapter).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a native API that exposes this information, either WMI or Performance Monitor, which is typically what is leveraged by PowerShell. The network usage data is stored in a Microsoft Jet database, located at:  C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat.  This is functionality included in the  System Resource Usage Monitor (SRUM), which is part of the Diagnostic Policy Service.

More information:

https://velociraptor.velocidex.com/digging-into-the-system-resource-usage-monitor-srum-afbadb1a375?gi=86dfb98a4bb6

https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/28/networkusageview-lists-windows-network-usage-data/

Comment: I wish someone [Crescendo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.crescendo/?view=ps-modules)'d the [NirSoft ESEDatabaseView CLI](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ese_database_view.html) tool.

Comment: @AyanMullick: I don't think that would be needed. It's a database with a simple table. This could be a TSQL cmdlet or similar.

Comment: Is there an example of the TSQL to query the data consumption per process from SRUDB.dat so that one could query it from a Windows terminal?